# joomla update error in sql

Tags: joomla

I see this message in joomla 3 update page:

```
An error has occurred.
0 SQL=INSERT INTO `f1bz4_updates`(`update_site_id`,`extension_id`,`name`,
`description`,`element`,`type`,`folder`,`client_id`,`version`,
`detailsurl`,`infourl`,`extra_query`) 
VALUES ('1','700','Joomla','','joomla','file','','0','3.4.8',
'http://update.joomla.org/core/sts/extension_sts.xml','','')
```

In phpMyAdmin I found them: [image: them].

How can I fix them?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your table lacks extra_query field. You might create it manually, if you wish. Just search for it in Joomla distribution package and find its parameters. Should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your table lacks the 'data' field. You might create it manually, if you wish. Just search for it in Joomla distribution package and find its parameters. Should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Login to Administrator >> Extension manager >> Database > click on "Fix" database button at left right corner.

It will all ok :)